# Making upvotes happen instantly (Rails + MySQL + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm struggling with how to architect an "upvote" flow using Rails & jQuery, such that the upvote happens instantly as far as the end user is concerned.

So first, to define upvote, I mean like you would do on reddit, where clicking an up-arrow registers a vote for a record, and increments a counter (a thumbs-up on YouTube is another example).

I'm using Rails 3.2, jQuery, and MySQL for the db.

Right now my flow is this:

1. In the html.erb template, the upvote element has a `.js-remote-upvote` class which binds it to a click using jQuery:

   `$('body').on('click', '.js-remote-upvote', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $this = $(e.currentTarget);
     $.ajax({
       type: $this.data('method') == "post" ? "POST" : "GET",
       url: $this.data('url')
     })
   });`
2. The `data-url` goes to my UpvotesController toggle action, which creates the upvote record, and takes care of some other misc. things.
3. The toggle.js.erb template then contains the javascript code that adds an `.active` class on the upvote element, and increments the counter.

The problem is that no matter how much I try to lean out the toggle action in the controller, it consumes some time (application wide before_filters, tracking, stuff like that). This leads to an upvote not feeling instantaneous to the end user, which I feel makes for a bad UX when we are used to upvotes happening instantly on reddit.

Am I thinking about this the right way? Or should I increment the counter and set the `.active` css class right away *before* the request is passed on to Rails? That feels wrong to me, since the controller could throw an exception - basically it feels like the js is "dumb" and will just show the user an instant upvote no matter what happens on the backend.

Would that be a bad pattern to adopt?
Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you to show that user voted immediately. This is not that kind of information which requires lot of safety. If something went wrong on next page reload this vote dissapear, so you wont be worrying about somebody upvote infitite times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did the same but using a trick..As a software developer,only we are aware whats happening behind the scenes.So no matter how hard you try,You have to store the `upvote` count,who clicked `upvote`,has count `incremted`...etc details and then update the view as well.

***INSTEAD OF GOING TO THE SERVER AND UPDATING THE DETAILS IN DB AND THEN UPDATING THE VIEW..YOU CAN FIRST UPDATE/CHANGE THE VIEW AND THEN MOVE TO THE SERVER USING AJAX WHICH LOOKS FAST FOR USER.***

So first for **Good User Experience**..**FIRST** **update the view code using jquery and then use ajax to call method from the controller that updates the vote**...So atleast for the user,**its instant** and you know that behind the scenes,it takes atleast 2 seconds...

**in view file...**

```
####update the count and also show that user has voted successfully by jquery
$('#image_up_<%= @image.id%>').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
$(".user_vote_status").html("You like this Image");
```

**server side ...update the details and update the view again for confirmation**

```
  def vote

  @image = Image.find(params[:id]) 
  ###method to add count by current user
  @image.vote_by_current_user(current_user.id,params[:type]) 
  ###code to update the count 
  ## reload to get latest count
  @image.reload

  respond_to :js
end
```

**in vote.js.erb**

```
 $('#image_up_<%= @image.id%>').html("<%= @image.likes.size %>");
 //update the vote status on the page that user has liked/disliked the post
$(".user_vote_status").html("You like this Image");
```